# How to change menu text when resizing window with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change the menu text automatically when resizing the window to `768px` or lower.

Any solution for that?

The code below doesn't work.

```
function menu() {
  let w = window.outerWidth;
  let y = document.getElementById("home");

  if (w <= 768) {
    y.innerText = "Menu";
  } else {
    y.innerText = "Home";
  }
}

menu();
```

Comment: You can use CSS for this. Why are you doing this with Javascript?

Comment: so use window resize? bind the event listener.... Does not work is also not helpful description of the problem.

Comment: I know I just wanted to use js for practice? Is it actually possible to do it with js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works, you probably just need to call it whenever the [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) fires. Ex, if the above code is in a a function called "menu":

```
function menu(){
    let w = window.outerWidth;
    let y = document.getElementById("home");

    if (w <= 768) {
        y.innerText = "Menu";
    } else {
        y.innerText = "Home";
    }
}

window.onresize = menu;
```

That said, though, it makes much more sense to do this with CSS [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).